# R Shiny: Latex equations are not properly rendered

Tags: r, latex, shiny, r-markdown

I can't get ioslides to render latex equation. A simple example is:

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
date: "Tuesday, November 03, 2015"
output: ioslides_presentation
runtime: shiny
---

## slide 1

$\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$

The equation is rendered as \(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\
```

Note that I'm able to get the proper rendering if I create the file as RPresentation but not as ioslides.

Answer (score 1):

ioslides needs to know that it has to use mathjax

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
date: "Tuesday, November 03, 2015"
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    mathjax: "http://example.com/mathjax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"
runtime: shiny
---

## slide 1

$\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$

The equation is rendered as \(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\
```

Comment: This example works on my machine. Did you copy paste the example? What was the output or error message **exactly**. "It didn't help" doesn't give us much to work on...

Comment: I copied your example and saved the file as .Rmd. Then I started the presentation by clicking on "Run Presentation". There were no error messages, but the latex expression wasn't rendered as a formula. Instead it displayed as "\(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\". I also tried opening the page in a browser and got the same result. Hope this detailed description helps. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a link to the resulting HTML file?

Comment: @madcap I think I have the same problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34024137/part-of-square-root-latex-equation-dissappears-in-pdf-rendering-from-rstudios-r) with rendering square root in my pdf_document. Your solution doesn't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out I needed to change the reference to MathJax in the deck header to:

output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    mathjax: "http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"

Note that I previously had the following reference to MathJax (which did not work):
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    mathjax: "http://example.com/mathjax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.