# part of square root latex equation dissappears in pdf rendering from RStudio's rmarkdown

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown, equation

When I use this code to make a square root in my pdf document (rendered by rmarkdown):

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "test test"
geometry: margin=1in
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
  html_document:
    css: tables.css
    number_sections: yes
    theme: cerulean
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
header-includes:
- \usepackage[dutch]{babel}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{this is a fancy foot}
- \usepackage{dcolumn}
- \usepackage{here}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{caption}
- \captionsetup{skip=2pt,labelsep=space,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=off}
subtitle: test test test
fontsize: 12pt
---

$$ S_E\text{=}S_x\sqrt{\text{(}\text{1}\text{-}r_{xx}\text{)}} $$
```

this is the result:

[image]

Notice the strange looking square root. Does anyone know what's going wrong here in my code?

Comment: it works fine on my machine. Are you sure the problem is not with your pdf viewer?

Comment: It's the recommended (by rstudio) viewer. I will check another one.

Comment: I checked several viewers. The all showed a missing part of the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem here:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210153/pdftex-font-expansion-error-during-compilation

In the directory `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64` I ran updmap.exe. After that the problem was solved.